# How can i extend exceptions to return a specified error code along with the usual message?

Tags: c#, exception

When i throw or catch any kind of an exception i would like to specify an error code along with it to be able to do something like the following:

```
Writeline(ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.Code);
```

can you show me a way or suggest something?

thank you all.

Comment: The way you do it with any class.  Derive from whatever exception class suits you best and add a property and constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1) If you are throwing your own exception, you can inherit from the exception class and add whatever properties you would like.

2) You can add name/value pairs to any Exception's [Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) dictionary.

From the MSDN documentation, to add information to Data:

```
   try
   {
       // do something
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
        e.Data["ExtraInfo"] = "Information from NestedRoutine1.";
        e.Data.Add("MoreExtraInfo", "More information from NestedRoutine1.");
        throw e;
   }
```

and to use that information:

```
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Extra details:");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in e.Data)
                Console.WriteLine("    The key is '{0}' and the value is: {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception` class defines a key/value dictionary for any custom data you need to store in the `Exception` instance — see the [`Exception.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property.